# Huge Dictionary and sub string lookup

Tags: c#, search

I have a dictionary with 500,000 keys and I have to compare using Key.contains("Description"). This is making my performance really slow. Is there any other alternative way to perform faster search?

I had List before but that performed even worse. Tried using Index on List but did not improve performance much.

Comment: Do you mean 500,000 or 5,000,000? Writing it as 500,0000 is very odd. And if using `IndexOf` on `List<string>` made it faster than a `Dictionary<string, Whatever>` then I'm *very* dubious of your testing methodology...

Comment: What do you mean compare using `Key.contains("Description")`? Can you post some code? Dictionary lookups should be very fast as long the hashes are generated well regardless of collection size.

Comment: @ZongZhengLi But he's *not* doing a dictionary lookup; he wants to see if the key contains a string, not that it's equal to a string.

Comment: if you are familiar with [Lucene.Net](http://lucenenet.apache.org/) you can use [SingleCharTokenAnalyzer](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene.net/trunk/src/contrib/Core/Analysis/Ext/Analysis.Ext.cs) which is suitable for  `*description*` like queries

Comment: Number of keys are 500K. I meant Index as IndexableCollection<T>

Comment: @Servy I'm not so sure...why does OP mention using a list and `indexOf` then?

Comment: you are trying to do a fundamentally hard thing. If you know that the string you look for is always 'Descriptionxxx' then rearrange the key before inserting in the dicitonary. Otherwise you are stuck with linear search (or really expensive choices of indexing by every sub string)

Comment: @ZongZhengLi He *doesn't* mention the use of `IndexOf`...

Comment: @Servy How should one interpret "Tried using Index on List"?

Comment: @ZongZhengLi I really have no idea what it means.  I interpreted it as simply doing a linear search on it, as that's really the only way to solve the problem.  Presumably he wasn't familiar with that term.

Comment: sorry for confusion @Zong, I meant Index as IndexableCollection<T>. Suprising that I completely forgot that someone might think of IndexOf

Comment: Is there a pattern in your keys that you can use to split them in groups? Like creating multiple sub-dictionaries from that huge one...

Comment: There are list of properties in database for a given lender, now user can enter five descriptions with comma. So current implementation is like    boCol = from bo in _properties
                        where ((Property)bo).PropertyDescription.Contains(param[0])
                           && ((Property)bo).PropertyDescription.Contains(param[1])
 && ((Property)bo).PropertyDescription.Contains(param[2])
 && ((Property)bo).PropertyDescription.Contains(param[3])
                           && ((Property)bo).PropertyDescription.Contains(param[4])
                        select bo;

Comment: But there must be a way to categorize or group those properties somehow. Or couldn't just to the query in the DB instead of dumpling the whole thing in a dictionary? It's probably faster

Comment: In-memory search was chosen by previous developers because they thought it will perform better. I have not really looked at the difference between database call and in memory search but the stored proc which brings data is really messy.

Comment: Could you post a Sample Property Description and the 5 search params? I'm just trying to get ideas..

Comment: Sample property: tell Telle Carraige Sawmill Rh-ccxxH440xxx38.5Hyv-Op-rL-2008 and description can be carriage, Sawmill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than storing all possible substrings of all possible keys as the keys in the dictionary (which you almost certainly wouldn't have enough memory to do) there really isn't much to be done besides iterating through the entire collection and doing the check on each item.  Given that you're iterating the entire collection, there's not really much benefit to using a `Dictionary` over a `List`, at least for this specific operation (perhaps other operations you perform on this data benefit from it being in a `Dictionary`).  They're both going to be quite slow.  You simply have an inherently expensive operation that you're trying to perform.

If you can alter your requirements somehow to search for a string exactly equal to your search string then you can use the dictionary's hash based lookup, which is super fast, and if you could use a `StartsWith` or `EndsWith` operation instead of a full `Contains` then you could sort the data and use a binary search, but with a `Contains` operation none of those optimizations can be made.

Comment: Thanks Servy. I converted a  few Collections to dictionaries and removed linq operations in favor of straight forward lookup using dictionary. But those were simple case with equality search. This operation is based on "%Like%/contains"  operator. So Here I am stuck.

Comment: I think at this point I will try to change requirement so that a little simpler search could be done.

Answer (score 1):

If the search is performed multiple times, you may want to consider using extra collections holding just the items that match a predefined condition.

These collections would be populated at the same time your original dictionary is populated.

This could be a viable solution if you have a limited number of fixed searches.

Answer (score 0):

I've read that by doing Regex you get an extra overhead, but why don't you benchmark it yourself?

Something like this:

```
        var test = "Telle Carraige Sawmill Rh-ccxxH440xxx38.5Hyv-Op-rL-2008";
        var matchCollection = Regex.Matches(test, "(Carraige|Sawmill)",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        //matchCollection.Count should be == 2
```

Comment: Sure,one more alternative to look at, although as you said regex can cause overhead. Will find that soon.

Comment: From my instrumentation tests in VS 2013, it doesn't look good. `Regex.Matches` is a performance killer..